# Prepend prefix to list elements with list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Having a list like this:

```
['foo','spam','bar']
```

is it possible, using list comprehension, to obtain this list as result?

```
['foo','ok.foo', 'spam', 'ok.spam', 'bar', 'ok.bar']
```

Comment: It's a "list comprehension", not "list of comprehension" ;)

Comment: "Append prefix" is an oxymoron, should be prepend/prefix

Comment: geez you guys are harsh

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
In [67]: alist = ['foo','spam', 'bar']

In [70]: [prefix+elt for elt in alist for prefix in ('','ok.') ]
Out[70]: ['foo', 'ok.foo', 'spam', 'ok.spam', 'bar', 'ok.bar']
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I used the exact same idea to pad a list with empty list elements like so: *[[]] + [empty+[] for char in [[i] for i in range(len(text))] for empty in (char,[])]* which results in a list like so: *[[],[i],[],[o],[],[u],[]]*. So this is useful for more than creating a list of concatenated strings if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 1):

With list comprehensions, you're creating new lists, not appending elements to an existing list (which may be relevant on really large datasets)

Why does it have to be a list comprehension anyway? Just because python has them doesn't make it bad coding practice to use a for-loop.