# Merging two Excel files by ID and combining columns with same name (python, pandas)

Tags: python, excel, merge, pandas

I am new to stackoverflow and pandas for python.  I found part of my answer in the post [Looking to merge two Excel files by ID into one Excel file using Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661836/looking-to-merge-two-excel-files-by-id-into-one-excel-file-using-python-2-7)

However, I also want to merge or combine columns from the two excel files with the same name.  I thought the following post would have my answer but I guess it's not titled correctly: [Merging Pandas DataFrames with the same column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862068/merging-pandas-dataframes-with-the-same-column-name)

Right now I have the code:

```
import pandas as pd

file1 = pd.read_excel("file1.xlsx")
file2 = pd.read_excel("file2.xlsx")

file3 = file1.merge(file2, on="ID", how="outer")

file3.to_excel("merged.xlsx")
```

file1.xlsx

ID,JanSales,FebSales,test
1,100,200,cars
2,200,500,
3,300,400,boats

file2.xlsx

ID,CreditScore,EMMAScore,test
2,good,Watson,planes
3,okay,Thompson,
4,not-so-good,NA,

what I get is merged.xlsx

ID,JanSales,FebSales,**test_x**,CreditScore,EMMAScore,**test_y**
1,100,200,cars,NaN,NaN,
2,200,500,,good,Watson,planes
3,300,400,boats,okay,Thompson,
4,NaN,NaN,,not-so-good,NaN,

what I want is merged.xlsx

ID,JanSales,FebSales,CreditScore,EMMAScore,**test**
1,100,200,NaN,NaN,cars
2,200,500,good,Watson,planes
3,300,400,okay,Thompson,boats
4,NaN,NaN,not-so-good,NaN,NaA

In my real data, there are 200+ columns that correspond to the "test" column in my example.  I want the program to find these columns with the same names in both file1.xlsx and file2.xlsx and combine them in the merged file.

Comment: Are the values for 'test' column same in both excel files? Are the number of rows and IDS the same from both excel files? If the former then you can just drop one of the columns and rename the remaining column, if the latter then you can perform a merge without passing `how='outer'` as this will default to inner and will merge on ids that are present in both

Comment: @EdChum: the values for the 'test' column can be anything.  I just used even and odd to make the example simple. The number of rows/IDs in the two excel files will not be the same, in fact they will hardly ever have the same IDs.  I updated the example to reflect my real data more accurately.

Comment: When merging it will only rename the columns if the values do not match, this will create lots of NaN values in your case, what are the actual values as there may be other ways around this problem? A naive approach would be to do some post processing after merging, you know the ids and columns from one file and the other so you could use this to create the final value by selecting the values

Comment: @EdChum: the values can be anything, see updated post.  Having lots of NaN values is ok, actually that's what I expect. I basically want the code to look for columns with the same name in both files, and combine these into one column in the third file.  As I mention in the last paragraph, the real data would have **200+** columns that may have the same name in both files, making it tedious to select the columns/values.

Comment: I've updated my answer this should work for your situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, here is a more dynamic way, after merging we assume that clashes will occur and result in 'column_name_x' or '_y'.

So first figure out the common column names and remove 'ID' from this list

```
In [51]:

common_columns = list(set(list(df1.columns)) & set(list(df2.columns)))
common_columns.remove('ID')
common_columns
Out[51]:
['test']
```

Now we can iterate over this list to create the new column and use `where` to conditionally assign the value dependent on which value is not null.

```
In [59]:

for col in common_columns:
    df3[col] = df3[col+'_x'].where(df3[col+'_x'].notnull(), df3[col+'_y'])
df3
Out[59]:
   ID  JanSales  FebSales test_x  CreditScore EMMAScore  test_y    test
0   1       100       200   cars          NaN       NaN     NaN    cars
1   2       200       500    NaN         good    Watson  planes  planes
2   3       300       400  boats         okay  Thompson     NaN   boats
3   4       NaN       NaN    NaN  not-so-good       NaN     NaN     NaN

[4 rows x 8 columns]
```

Then just to finish off drop all the extra columns:

```
In [68]:

clash_names = [elt+suffix for elt in common_columns for suffix in ('_x','_y') ]
clash_names
df3.drop(labels=clash_names, axis=1,inplace=True)
df3
Out[68]:
   ID  JanSales  FebSales  CreditScore EMMAScore    test
0   1       100       200          NaN       NaN    cars
1   2       200       500         good    Watson  planes
2   3       300       400         okay  Thompson   boats
3   4       NaN       NaN  not-so-good       NaN     NaN

[4 rows x 6 columns]
```

The snippet above is from this :[Prepend prefix to list elements with list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330880/prepend-prefix-to-list-elements-with-list-comprehension)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This would work if I was working on simple data such as in my example, but as I said in the last paragraph there are **200+** columns with the same name (i.e. test1, test2, ... test200) in df1 and df2 that I want to merge into one file.  I wouldn't know the names of these columns (the true names of the "test" columns is unknown) before hand to be able to conditionally select column values and drop extra columns.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer.  I was hoping pandas came with a method that accomplished, but your answer this certainly solves my problem.

Comment: @ferrios25 there may be a better way but I can't think of one at the moment, glad I could help